# Android Firebase: Checking if the current user id matches a list of user ids?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to check if the logged in user id matches the current user id to validate the user type.

I'm using the exists() method but doesn't seem to work. see code:

```
private String userID = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
private DatabaseReference database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("basenode");

database.child("sand").child("administratorCountry").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (dataSnapshot.child(userID).exists()) {
                System.out.println("THIS IS THE OUTPUT: "+ "TRUE");
            }else{
                System.out.println("THIS IS THE OUTPUT: "+ "FALSE");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

See Firebase structure:

[image]

I would appreciate any help! Thanks!

**UPDATED**

Data inside each user ID:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest attaching a listener directly to the `userID` node and then checking that the returned data exists:

```
private String userID = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
private DatabaseReference database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

database.child("sand")
    .child("administratorCountry")
    .child(userID) // Create a reference to the child node directly
    .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                // This callback will fire even if the node doesn't exist, so now check for existence
                if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                    System.out.println("The node exists.");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("The node does not exist.");
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) { }
        });
```

---

You don't need to specify `child("basenode")`, as the `getReference()` method points directly to the root of your database, so you can remove `child("basenode")` from the `database` variable.

Comment: Thanks Grimthorr. I'm getting FALSE as output but i'm currently logged in as "1v40TSTjw4XR5oLeZGPKcsa6xt12" which is on the list under "administratorCountry"...so not working. any suggestions?

Comment: Ok, just to confirm - the `administratorCountry` node is located at: `/basenode/sand`? If you add `System.out.println(dataSnapshot.getRef().toString());` to the `onDataChange()` method, does this point to the correct location?

Comment: it prints out perfectly fine : /basenode/sand/administratorCountry/1v40TSTjw4XR5oLeZGPKcsa6xt12

Comment: It should be working. What output do you get if you add `System.out.println(dataSnapshot.getValue().toString());` to `onDataChange()`?

Comment: i'm getting the following error after printout: "java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference"

Comment: The `/basenode/sand/administratorCountry/1v40TSTjw4XR5oLeZGPKcsa6‌​xt12` location doesn't exist then. Can you try exporting your database structure as JSON from the Firebase Console database section (3-dot overflow menu, export JSON)? Then you can see the exact node names, and check if they have whitespace at the end or something similar.

Comment: hey Grimthorr, I tried and it seems fine. it's exists and no space or anything. is it because it has other data inside the ID? see question UPDATED

Comment: It could be, but then `getValue()` should not be returning `null`. You could try swapping `exists()` for `hasChildren()` then?

Comment: Nope. Same FALSE

Comment: So `FirebaseAuth#getCurrentUser().getUid()` returns `1v40TSTjw4XR5oLeZGPKcsa6xt12`? If the database is returning a `DataSnapshot` with a `null` value, no children and `exists() == false` then the location specified in the `DatabaseReference` does not exist. Can you try manually adding another node with key of `test` to the `administratorCountry` list and then try changing `child(userID)` to `child("test")` to see if this actually retrieves this value?

Comment: Hey Grimthorr, it works now!...i think firebase has changed...we now don't have to specify the base node. Anyway, much appreciate your time. if you update your answer, i would like to tick yours as the answer.